# Как составить рабочий POST запрос (request)?

Tags: python, html, post, requests

Помогите сделать правильный и рабочий POST запрос. Пытаюсь сделать по книжке, но не получается.

**Как выглядит успешный процесс, который требуется ?**

Ссылка для продолжения регистрации (подтверждения пароля) приходит на почту >>> переходим по ссылке >>> вводим пароль два раза (два поля) >>> отправляем POST запрос >>> получаем успешный ответ.

**Что нужно сделать, где ошибка ?**

Нужно сделать подтверждения аккаунта, а именно, установить ему пароль через POST Запрос.

[image: сайт www.geoguessr.com]

**Как выглядит успешный запрос ?** (скриншот ниже)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Успешный запрос 2]

**Мой код:**

```
import requests

# https://www.geoguessr.com/profile/set-password/RJ4EDR73H5ohCjFZexf7yIrrhVKBjEAC - ССЫЛКА КОТОРАЯ ПРИХОДИТ НА ПОЧТУ

url = 'https://www.geoguessr.com/api/v3/profiles/setpassword'

headers = {
    'Host': 'www.geoguessr.com',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Length': '63',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Origin': 'https://www.geoguessr.com',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Referer': 'https://www.geoguessr.com/profile/set-password/RJ4EDR73H5ohCjFZexf7yIrrhVKBjEAC',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'Cookie': '_ga=GA1.2.1618825531.1614029072; __stripe_mid=e4666461-4648-4448-abe1-d71911d357ae21a085; devicetoken=4CDC3DDBF0; _gid=GA1.2.185317881.1617285432; _gat_gtag_UA_40205730_2=1'
}

request = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data={'token': 'RJ4EDR73H5ohCjFZexf7yIrrhVKBjEAC', 'password': '12345'})


print('\n', request.status_code)
print(request.text)
```

**Какую я получаю ошибку?**

```
 400
{"message": "Bad request"}
```

**Данные и ссылки для проделывания запроса:**

Ссылка которая приходит на почту:

https://www.geoguessr.com/profile/set-password/RJ4EDR73H5ohCjFZexf7yIrrhVKBjEAC

Какой пароль нужно установить:

Желательно "12345" так как делаю все в тест режиме.

P.S. Если нужно больше ссылок для регистрации, могу обновить и прикрепить ещё несколько. Так как возможно со старой что-то случиться.

Буду благодарен за любую мысль и помощь. Спасибо.

Comment: 1. не пробовали в requests.post() вместо data= указать json=? 2. если вы по "использованной" ссылке из письма пытаетсь второй раз установить пароль - ничего не выйдет: ссылка одноразовая

Comment: @Jack_oS 1. Установил json, появилась новая ошибка "401
{"message": "You are not allowed to do this."}".  2. Это я понимаю и нет, я почти каждый раз пробую зайти на тот аккаунт, то есть с тем паролем что передаю, но безрезультатно.

Comment: @Jack_oS Джек, кажется Вы мне помогли! Сейчас отпишусь, я пересоздал ссылки ещё раз, вписал json=... , и получил ответ:  200 
{"email":null,"nick":"Fapasel158","isProUser":false,"isVerified":false,"pin":{"url":"","anchor":"center-center","isDefault":true},"color":0,"url":"/user/606c35c2c8d8110001fd8c2b","id":"606c35c2c8d8110001fd8c2b","countryCode":null,"br":{"level":0,"division":0},"streakProgress":null,"explorerProgress":null,"dailyChallengeProgress":0}. Не такой как всегда) По сути ответ про данные аккаунта. Скоро отпишусь

Comment: @Jack_oS, все работает, огромное спасибо!!! Может напишите в ответ, чтобы я пометил его правильным ? А ещё такой вопрос, headers у меня все подобраны правильно? Нужно брать все headers которые есть в "request headers" или как-то можно только главные? не подскажете?

Comment: @Jack_oS, Я могу как-то присвоить вашему комментарию режим "ответ" ?

Comment: нет, это же комментарий, а принять можно только ответ... не тянет это на ответ ))

Comment: @Jack_oS, ну самый первый Ваш комментарий и помог мне решить мою проблему. Ну если захотите - поставите это в ответ. Благодарю.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в заголовках есть `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`, то и отправлять нужно в requests параметре json (вместо data):

```
data = {
    'token': 'my_token', 
    'password': 'my_password'}

...

request = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
```

либо как json.dumps:

```
import json

data = {
    'token': 'my_token', 
    'password': 'my_password'}

...

request = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
```